# Minimum length of a sequence containing n

Tags: optimization, computational-mathematics

An infinite number of boards are lined up, and the number $1$ is written on the first board.

Write the numbers on the board from the left, but the number written on the $n$th board can only be the sum of the two numbers written on the $1$st to $n-1$th boards.  (It is allowed to draw two numbers from the same board and write the sum of the numbers.)

Let f(x) be the minimum position on the board where x can appear.

For example, $1,2,3,4,5$ are possible and $1,2,4,5$ are also possible and $3$th boards's number can only $3$ or $4$. From this, you can know $f(5)=4$.

I think it so hardly but I cannot think answer.
I proved $f(mn) \leq f(m)+f(n)-1$. This is simply proved. If $(a_1 , a_2, ...,a_{f(n)}=n)$ and $(b_1 , b_2, ...,b_{f(m)}=m)$ are possible then $(a_1, a_2, ...,a_{f(n)}=n=nb_1, nb_2, ..., nb_{f(m)}=nm)$ are possible. So $f(nm) \leq f(n)+f(m)-1$.

I think If $n$ is prime, $f(mn) = f(m)+f(n)-1$.(Maybe be wrong) So I think we can find a function using the function values ​​for all prime numbers.

Is my guess correct? How can I find the function $f$?

Comment: Asking just in case this matters (I don't know if this in any way influences the solution): is $1,2,2,2,\ldots$ possible/allowed? (Each $2$ is a sum of two $1$'s in front.). It doesn't look like doing that would make it easier to get some numbers on the board, but still...

Comment: Are you saying there can be multiple numbers written on each board?

Comment: Is $f(nm) \leq f(n)+f(m)-1$ true?  For example, is it true for $n=3, m=5, nm=15$?  I think $f(3)=3, f(5)=4, f(15)=7$

Comment: @Henry $(1,2,3,6,12,15)$ are possible so $f(15) \leq 6$

Comment: @추민서 Fair enough

Comment: @StinkingBishop It is possible. but multiple numbers do not appear in a sequence containing $n$ and having the minimum length

Comment: These are called [addition chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition_chain) and your $f$ is [OEIS A265690](https://oeis.org/A265690) though $f-1$ is more commonly investigated and is [OEIS A003313](https://oeis.org/A003313) with a pile of links

Comment: @추민서 How quickly can you get $7$? If you allow multiple numbers, you can have it as $1, 2, (3;4), 7$ while I cannot see how you can get $7$ on the fourth board if each board can have only one number on it.

Comment: @StinkingBishop I misunderstand your comment. I understand this comment to ask if $1,2,2,2,2.....$ is possible.

Comment: @추민서 Those were two separate questions.

Comment: @StinkingBishop each board can have only one number on it. multiple number is not allowed.